# Pandas DataFrame: complete spec for __getitem__()?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

## Short version

For pandas `Dataframe.__getitem__()`, what are the allowed inputs (input types really), and what results does the function produce as a result?

## Details

### Description of problem

I would like to write code that makes full use of DataFrame[], essentially `Dataframe.__getitem__()`.  To that end, I would like information on inputs/return results, at the level of detail found on the API page, though not available there for this method.

### What has been done so far to solve it

I looked for a complete spec for that function at the [Pandas API page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html). Though many other methods are documented, `Dataframe.__getitem__()` is not.

I also looked at [the tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html), but I don't believe that's attempting to be exhaustive.

I did look at the source code for `Dataframe.__getitem__()` (first pass at this described in my own answer below). It's evident that a variety of quite different types can be accepted as input, but reverse engineering the code to determine what happens when each of those types is passed seems like it can't be the intended way to master this method.

#### Additional background

Pandas is one of the most important libraries in Python's role in science and statistics, DataFrame is arguably the most central object in Pandas, and the `[]` operator is arguably the most central method on DataFrame. Hence, actually answering the question I have posted here has a very high pedagogical value, not just some utility for me.

Comment: Have you looked at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I have, and that's OK for a tutorial, but I'm looking for a comprehensive and definitive spec of what all DataFrame[] can accept (and do with that), not just some samples. After all, the rest of the API has formal doc, so I'm assuming that [] must have too, somewhere.

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* - I suggest you continue to look through the existing documentation for what you are interested in.

Comment: I am not asking for a recommendation, I am asking where is the authoritative doc for this function. That's pretty specific. The answers might be "the doc is at xxx", or "there is no doc", or perhaps "the developers didn't create a doc, but fred smith did, and it's at xxx". No opinion required. That function has certain well-defined functionality, and I'd like to know what that is, preferably from an authoritative source.

Comment: And I have looked through the docs, and searched using their search function, to no avail. I am now following the instructions at here: http://pandas.pydata.org/community.html  "Your first stop should be Stack Overflow."

Comment: You are asking for someone to find an off-site resource for you, which is *explicitly off-topic*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69061/discussion-between-gwideman-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: The question stated as "*What is the complete spec for what this function accepts and returns?*" is a good and interesting question I think. And the answer unfortunately is: there is no complete description of this, apart from the tutorial docs (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics) and the code itself. But, this would certainly be useful to have. There is actually an issue about this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6920

Comment: Thank you @joris. I appreciate that you get the point and merit of the question, and I thank you for both your off-site links (though I had seen the tutorial before). They don't completely satisfy what I'm looking for, but the github link illuminates the state-of-play in getting to an answer, which is helpful.

Comment: `__getitem__()` is the python-specified implementation of the list indexing operator `[ ]`.  See [3.4. Special method names](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) You will likely need to read the source code and determine for yourself how the authors of Pandas implement indexing.

Comment: @JimGarrison But as this usage of `[ ]` is implemented in a very specific way for the `DataFrame` object, it would be interesting to have reference docs about this.

Comment: @gwideman In any case (however you are totally right there are some docs missing), for more compley code I would always advice to use `.iloc[]/.loc[]` to be very explicit about label-based vs position-based indexing (as `[]` can be both depending on the situation, just like `ix` which is documented a bit more)

Comment: @joris yes, I agree that the territory of [] extends into or overlaps with .iloc, loc and ix -- a doc regarding the entire territory would, I think, be very helpful to users.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, ``getitem__()`` is the implementation of [] in python, which is why I'm looking at it. And looking at the source is an option, which I explored in my initial answer. Do you have further insight beyond this that I missed?

Answer (score 9):

I'm suspecting part of the lack of doc for this function is due to lack of doc comments in the source, now that I look at it. In case nobody comes up with anything more user-friendly, here's the actual `DataFrame.__getitem__()` method:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):

    # shortcut if we are an actual column
    is_mi_columns = isinstance(self.columns, MultiIndex)
    try:
        if key in self.columns and not is_mi_columns:
            return self._getitem_column(key)
    except:
        pass

    # see if we can slice the rows
    indexer = _convert_to_index_sliceable(self, key)
    if indexer is not None:
        return self._getitem_slice(indexer)

    if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, list)):
        # either boolean or fancy integer index
        return self._getitem_array(key)
    elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
        return self._getitem_frame(key)
    elif is_mi_columns:
        return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
    else:
        return self._getitem_column(key)
```

... which at least gives a top-level breakdown of the kinds of key (index) that DataFrame[] accepts.