# Pandas boolean selection with `loc` is not always faster?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, indexing

As I know of in `Pandas`, boolean selection with `loc` is much faster than the one with just using boolean selection

Here is my experiment:

[image]

**First experiment with single column**

```
%%timeit
df[df['종가']>9700]['시가총액']
>> 727 µs ± 2.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


%%timeit
df.loc[df['종가']>9700, "시가총액"]
>> 362 µs ± 456 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Using `loc` is much faster as I expected

**Second experiment with multiple columns**

```
%%timeit
df[df['종가']>9700][['시가총액', '유통시가총액']]
>> 1.15 ms ± 22.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
df.loc[df['종가']>9700, ['시가총액', '유통시가총액']]
>>  1.47 ms ± 50 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

In this time, using `loc` is slower...

I want to know why this performance difference happend

Comment: You can look at this question ,almost same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45196149/speed-of-pandas-df-locx-column

Answer (score 0):

> Using `loc` is much faster as I expected...this time, using `loc` is slower...I want to know why this performance difference happened.

There is nothing to say that `loc` *should* be faster. It may be faster, or slower, than other methods. The logic and functionality in [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is very different to [`pd.DataFrame.__getitem__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009873/pandas-dataframe-complete-spec-for-getitem), the latter being the method called by syntactic sugar `[]`.

Since Pandas is open-source, you can look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas) yourself. As implementations are *details liable to change without notice*, dissecting the API source code is often not a fruitful activity.

One potential reason is `loc` has many use cases, as explained in [Different Choices for Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing), with functionality that is not identical to `__getitem__`. In the use case you have described, you should avoid chained indexing, which is [explicitly discouraged](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) in the documentation.

If performance is an issue, you can consider [some alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45196149/speed-of-pandas-df-locx-column).